# How to send Dialogflow response to Cloud-Pub-Sub asynchronously

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to asynchronously publish the messages google cloud. I have searched alot but it couldn't help. I am new to node.js and google cloud, your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could describe what you have set up and if there are specific things with which you are having problems. Do you have any code that is not working as expected that you can share?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have achieved the above by using promises and GCP cloud pub sub node js module.

Comment: In this case, consider posting the solution as an answer in case someone else finds it useful